# Return to previous activity

Tags: android, http

I currently have two activities doing HTTP requests. On the second activity, there is a previous button. I would like to be able to go back on the first activity without losing information because at the moment I lose all the information recovered.

First activity:

```
public class GetChildrenList extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private ArrayList<Child> childrenImeList = new ArrayList<Child>();

private ListView itemsListView;
private TextView tv_signin_success;

String email;
String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get_children_list);

    String infos_user = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("infos_user");

    tv_signin_success = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_signin_success);


    tv_signin_success.setText("Bonjour " + infos_user + "!");

    itemsListView  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_children);


    new GetChildrenAsync().execute();
}

class GetChildrenAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Child>>  {

    private Dialog loadingDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GetChildrenList.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Child> doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream is = null;

        int statusCode = 0;
        int id = 0;
        int age = 0;
        email = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("email");
        password = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("password");
        String result = null;
        String first_name = null;
        String last_name = null;


        try {
            //Http request to communicate with our system
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
            URI website = new URI("http://192.168.1.33:5000/childrenime/list");
            httpGet.setURI(website);

            String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(
                    (email + ":" + password).getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);

            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            String jsonResult = "{ \"children\":" + result + "}";

            Log.d("result1", jsonResult);

            //Manage JSON result
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray childrenArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("children");

            for (int i = 0; i < childrenArray.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject child = childrenArray.getJSONObject(i);
                id = child.getInt("id");
                first_name = child.getString("first_name");
                last_name = child.getString("last_name");
                age = child.getInt("age");

                String name = first_name + " " + last_name;

                childrenImeList.add(new Child(id,name,age));
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return childrenImeList;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Child> childrenListInformation) {
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
        CustomListChildrenAdapter adapter = new CustomListChildrenAdapter(GetChildrenList.this, childrenListInformation);
        itemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
  }
}
```

Second activity:

```
public class GetLearningGoalsList extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private ArrayList<LearningGoal> childrenLearningList = new ArrayList<LearningGoal>();

private Button btn_previous;
private ListView itemsListView;

String email;
String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get_learning_goals_list);

    btn_previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);

    btn_previous.setOnClickListener(this);

    itemsListView  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view_learning_goals);


    new GetLearningGoalsAsync().execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(GetLearningGoalsList.this, GetChildrenList.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
    return;
}

class GetLearningGoalsAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<LearningGoal>>  {

    private Dialog loadingDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GetLearningGoalsList.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<LearningGoal> doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream is = null;

        int statusCode = 0;
        int id = 0;
        email = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("email");
        password = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("password");
        int idChild = (int) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("idChild");
        String json = null;
        String result = null;
        String name = null;
        String start_date = null;
        String end_date = null;

        try {
            //Http request to communicate with our system
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
            URI website = new URI("http://192.168.1.33:5000/learningchild/list");
            httpPost.setURI(website);

            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            jsonObj.accumulate("idChild", idChild);

            json = jsonObj.toString();

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(
                    (email + ":" + password).getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);

            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            String jsonResult = "{ \"learningGoals\":" + result + "}";

            Log.d("result1", jsonResult);

            //Manage JSON result
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray learningGoalsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("learningGoals");

            for (int i = 0; i < learningGoalsArray.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject learningGoal = learningGoalsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                id = learningGoal.getInt("id");
                name = learningGoal.getString("name");
                start_date = learningGoal.getString("start_date");
                end_date = learningGoal.getString("end_date");


                childrenLearningList.add(new LearningGoal(id,name,start_date,end_date));
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return childrenLearningList;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<LearningGoal> learningListInformation) {
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
        CustomListLearningGoalAdapter adapter = new CustomListLearningGoalAdapter(GetLearningGoalsList.this, learningListInformation);
        itemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do so that I do not lose information?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can save your data into SharedPreferences

Comment: You might want to look at the startActivityForResult method. It is however dependent of your usecase which is hard to determine based on your current questiion.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to save your data.

1. First, create SharedPreferences on the second activity:

   ```
   SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
       .getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE); 
   Editor editor = pref.edit();
   ```
2. Then store your data as `KEY/VALUE` pair:

   ```
   editor.putString("key", "string value");
   editor.commit();
   ```
3. Then get the data on the first activity:

   ```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   String value = mSharedPreference.getString("key", "");
   ```

On [Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126) there are some SharedPreferences basics you can follow.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted implement the SharedPreferences but between my two activities I have a class extends BaseAdapter and I have a data "infos_user" that doesn't store in my second activity ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to know is that there are several ways to retain information, it all depends on what and how.

- Data can be saved by overriding the "onSaveInstanceState" method to save the data:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle iOutState)
  {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(iOutState);

      iOutState.putString("USER_INFORMATION", infos_user);
      iOutState.putInt("CHILD_ID", idChild);
  }
  ```

  And overriding the "onRestoreInstanceState" method to load the saved data:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle iSavedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(iSavedInstanceState);
      infos_user = iSavedInstanceState.getString("USER_INFORMATION");
      idChild = iSavedInstanceState.getInt("CHILD_ID");
  }
  ```

So that when the activity states changes it saves the variables' last values and restores them when necessary.

- Data can be saved in a singleton.
- Data can be saved more permanently using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) or [SQLite DB](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Furthermore, you did not provide enough information, but if I understand correctly you first invoke "GetChildrenList" activity, then  "GetLearningGoalsList" and finally you click the previous button to go back to "GetChildrenList". **IF** that is the case, you need to understand that by default activities don't run as a single entity like a singleton for example, but rather gets created in every "startActivity" invoke. In other words, every time you invoke a "startActivity" command you create **a brand new** activity, so you end up with 3 activities; 2 of class "GetChildrenList" and one of "GetLearningGoalsList". To fix that either:

- Invoke "onBackPressed" method when pressing the previous button.
- Set the "GetChildrenList" launch mode to "singleInstance". that could be done in the manifest or as a flag in the intent used to start an activity.
  There are several types of launch mode other then "singleInstance".
  More information can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Good luck =)